# Make list group overlap with div

Tags: css, overlap

Can someone help me make my list group overlap with a `<div>` that contains a paragraph whenever a user types text in an input box? I tried making the `<ul>` element `position:relative` and the paragraph `position:absolute` but without success...

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Enter text here..." />
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>Uno</li>
    <li>Dos</li>
    <li>Tres</li>
    <li>Cuatro</li>
    <li>Cinco</li>
    <li>Siete</li>
    <li>Ocho</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div  class="below">
  <p>
    this is a basic paragraph that should be overlapped by the list group...
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.myList {
  position: relative;
}

.below {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$("#myList").hide()

$("#myInput").on('input', function () {
   if($("#myInput").val().length > 0) {
      $("#myList").show();
   } else {
    $("#myList").hide();
   }
});
```

here is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ydc8pzmw/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does `#myList {position: absolute;}` solve your problem?

Comment: hi - i tried that but it didn't work...

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap"? Should the list group be moved up so that it is closer to the input text box; or, something else?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/1qffmnue/.  Is that not what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: oh yes that's perfect @RickHitchcock... i had a typo when i tried it the first time.. Thanks!!

Comment: Whew, I was confused.  I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style:

```
#myList {
  position: absolute;
}
```

That will take the `<ul>` outside the document flow, so it won't affect the placement of the following `<div>`.

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1qffmnue/1)